# Copy to clipboard in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying all day to have this working and I can't...
I have tried:
- flash versions (at least 3 different ones)
- document.execCommand("copy") in content script, but also in background page
I've checked numerous pages on stackoverflow... every available solution.

Does anyone have a working example?

EDIT:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "test",
    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["https://somesite.com*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "css": ["style.css"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
            "clipboardWrite",
            "clipboardRead"
    ]
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('<textarea id="test"/>');
    var $test = $('#test');
    $test.text('some text which should appear in clipboard');
    $test.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('copied!');
});
```

Above doesn't work. Alert is shown...

EDIT2:
I've also tried with flash versions, but it possibly doesn't work because of that extension is something that is run on localhost, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy works strangely.  You should register an event listener for the copy, then this will be called when you do the `document.execCommand('copy')`.

This is a working example of the event handler:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  var textToPutOnClipboard = "some text which should appear in clipboard";
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', textToPutOnClipboard);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've got permissions for copy in your manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
  "clipboardWrite", // for copy and cut
  "clipboardRead", // for paste

],
```

and then use `document.execCommand('copy')` once something is selected

More info [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html).

Comment: Also thx for help, do you see something wrong in my code (see edited question)?